# WPF rendering slow performance

Tags: wpf, performance

I'm trying to improve the performance of my treeview in WPF, when you open a node with 6000 children, it takes about 13 seconds currently to display this. I am using an observablecollection for the child collection, with a datatemplate bound to the TransactionViewModel type which has about 7 columns, each pulling in a piece of data from the view model.

The transactionviewmodels for the 6000 children are created and instantiated, but as you haven't displayed any of them visually yet, the first time you expand the node, it takes the 13 seconds to display. if you then contract and expand the node, it displays instantly with zero time to display/load. The only difference I can see is that the first time each of the bound dependency properties of the TransactionviewModel has it's getter called by the XAML binding, and when you re-expand the second time, none of this happens as nothing has changed so WPF doesnt call the getters again and presumably just holds the bound information in memory for when you expand it the second time.

So the visual drawing of the control is instant, but the first time you open it (even though the 6000 transactionviewmodel objects are already fully loaded into the child collection), purely the rendering of the rows is what's taking the time.

Interestingly if I alter the datatemplate to not bind to ANY dependency properties on the viewmodel object and just output a blank grid, it still takes 8 seconds to load. So even without any data binding calls, the tree viewer takes 8 seconds to render 6000 rows. 5 seconds extra then gives you about 5 bound data columns per row, so that is a small cost compared to the basic rendering.

8s to render 6000 blank rows seems very high to me. Are there any major reasons why this might be happening or things to be aware of in rendering XAML into a treeview from data templates? Ive tried using just an empty datatemplate - ie not even a blank grid inside it and it still takes 7 seconds.

Given that it then collapses and expands instantly, why is it taking so long the first time when it isn't even rendering any XAML or calling any data bindings?

Also asynch calls are not a solution as my problem is not GUI responsitivy but time taken to load data. The user needs to have the data quicker than they are getting it right now.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using Virtualization? WPF does slow down when you start rendering thousands of UI objects, so typically you only want to render the visible items, not all of them, and simply replace the DataContext behind the controls as you scroll. I'd also double-check to be sure it's the UI rendering causing the delay, and not loading the data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to enable virtualization in the TreeView.

From [Optimizing Performance: Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716879(v=vs.90).aspx):

> By default, UI virtualization is enabled for the ListView and ListBox
>   controls when their list items are bound to data. TreeView
>   virtualization can be enabled by setting the
>   VirtualizingStackPanel::IsVirtualizing attached property to true

Comment: In my case it was VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing instead of VirtualizingStackPanel::IsVirtualizing

Comment: link is dead.. updated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls

Answer (score 3):

> If a TreeView contains many items, the amount of time it takes to load may cause a significant delay in the user interface. You can improve the load time by setting the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing attached property to true. The UI might also be slow to react when a user scrolls the TreeView by using the mouse wheel or dragging the thumb of a scrollbar. You can improve the performance of the TreeView when the user scrolls by setting the VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode attached property to Recycling.

[How to: Improve the Performance of a TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716882(v=vs.90).aspx)

XAML:

```
<TreeView Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataItems}}" x:Name="myTreeView" 
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
```

Programmatically:

```
myTreeView.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty, true);
myTreeView.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty, VirtualizationMode.Recycling)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely not rendering but layout - it has to instantiate a lot of UI elements to find the size of them so that it can properly size a number of UI elements (sliders), and this takes time. Rendering likely does not enter into this at all.

Comment: Is this just a limitation of the treeview control then? As all I am doing is adding blank child nodes and that still takes a reasonable amount of time. The second each row starts including small icon images, its nearly unusable. What tricks can I use to make this faster?